# Convert a GIF into a CUR file

Tags: image, mouse-cursor

How do you create a .cur (for a mouse cursor), from a GIF image file?

What tool or process can I use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use a cursor creator, which is pretty much just a bitmap with some header data.  I'd use Irfanview if you do not use Visual Studio or what not.  If you use Visual Studio, just create a new cursor, and copy and paste the image data right into the editor...  I'm sure I could whip up a tool that does this for you on a file basis, but I'm sure they are many tools out there already.

Comment: As you say, I copied the gif from paint.net to the editor in visual studio, (after adjusting to make it 32x32), then removed the background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[IconStudio](http://www.download.com/IconStudio/3000-2195_4-10389224.html) is able to aquire from other images.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a reference to a new tool called IconWorkshop lite which is a plugin for Visual Studio.  I thought of this question and figured I'd leave the link here for posterity.   I don't know for sure if it will do the job asked in the question...

http://sharptoolbox.com/tools/iconworkshop-lite

Comment: Thanks Jeff I'll definately give that a try next time.

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert it into a .ico which is more common and rename it with the .cur extension.