# C# Winforms - change cursor icon of mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-cursor

How to change cursor icon to the 'busy icon' usually shown on the desktop? How can i set Animated files (.gif,.ani) instead of cursor ?

Comment: Please correct(make it more concrete) the question and add your 2 answers into it too. Or may be "@Carlos Loth" already gave the right answer?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try to do the following:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

More information is available at [Cursors Class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursors.aspx)

Cursor class doesn't support GIF files or animated cursors (.ANI). You can load a custom cursor doing

```
Cursor.Current = new Cursor("C:\\ic.cur");
```

Maybe you can convert yout GIF file to cursor format using a tool like [Microangelo](http://www.microangelo.us/). In addition, there is another thread related to it.

[How do you convert a GIF into a CUR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426372/how-do-you-convert-a-gif-into-a-cur-file)

Comment: Then, "C:\ic.gif" should be "C:\ic.cur"?

Answer (score 3):

I have the answer for a picturebox

```
Picturebox1.cursor = new cursor(Properties.Resources.CURSOR NAME.GetHicon());
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also simple pure-C# way:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor cursor = null;      
var info = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(
        new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/MyCursor.cur"));
cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(info.Stream);
```

The MyCursor.cur must be included as Resource in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a ImageFile to .cur and add to Resources.

Change Cursor like this:

```
using (MemoryStream cursorStream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.myImageFile))
{
    textbox1.Cursor = new Cursor(cursorStream);
}
```