# Cursors in Visual Studio in a Winforms app using C#

Tags: c#, windows, mouse-cursor

I want to change my cursor when I load `frmCatch` to this cursor: `Application.StartupPath + @"\cursors\catch.ani"`.

I tried a lot of different options but it don't work.

I tried to use this code:

```cs
Cursor.Current = new Cursor(Application.StartupPath + @"\cursors\catch.ani");
```

And that is the error I get:

> System.ArgumentException: Image format is not valid. The image file may be corrupted. (Parameter 'fileName')

Comment: Unrelated: I'd recommend to `Path.Combine` paths.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902705/how-can-set-animated-cursors-ani-to-cursor - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3498898/14171304

Answer (score 1):

The [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.cursor.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-forms-cursor-ctor(system-string)) on `Cursor` clearly states:

> Note
> Animated cursors (.ani files) are not supported by the Cursor class.

So, that's the reason why you encounter this error. You may want to use a standard cursor (.cur) file.